# Why is this Mysql Descending query not returning as intended?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have this query:

```
SELECT product_list.id AS listId, product.prod_name AS prodName, FORMAT(MIN(pricelist.price),0) AS price 
FROM product_list 
INNER JOIN product ON product_list.id = product.prod_list_id 
INNER JOIN pricelist ON product.id = pricelist.prod_id 
WHERE product_list.id='2' 
GROUP BY listId, prodName 
ORDER BY price DESC
```

i want to make the price descending. can you tell me why this query return this:
[image: query result]

Comment: MySQL FORMAT returns string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FORMAT` function returns a string so you are not ordering based on integer values. You can use the inner call of that function to order and it will be by the integer value.

```
order by MIN(pricelist.price) desc
```